# Performance issue in String to Number conversion

Tags: java, string, performance

I have space separated string containing numbers in between like:

`"abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a"`

I have to parse the string to get the numbers from each token and then sum up all the digits extracted from tokens. I have written below code, but what I think is, if there is huge string, then there might be performance issue.

So, my questions are:

1. How can we improve the performance in below code?
2. Do we have another way to write the below code to solve the problem?

Code:

```
public class TestSum {

    public static int doSum(String str){
        String[] sArray = str.split(" ");
        char[] chr = null;
        String temp;
        String number = "";
        int sum=0;
        for(String s : sArray){
            chr = s.toCharArray();
            for(char c : chr){
                temp = String.valueOf(c);
                if(isNum(temp)){
                    number = number + temp;
                }           
            }
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(number);
            number="";
        }       
        return sum;
    }

    public static boolean isNum(String nStr){   
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(nStr);
            return true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            return false;
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Sum is "+ TestSum.doSum("abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a"));
    }
}
```

Comment: don't split string by ' '(space), you can just loop through every character and check if it's a digit and sum it.

Comment: I don't think your code even works: it returns 1379 for your example.

Comment: And: don't use raw string concatenation in a loop, use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Yep, using String concatenation and splitting is a real performance killer.  Anything else you do would be trivial by comparison.

Comment: Also that `isNum()` handcrafted method is 15x slower than simple `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

Answer (score 5):

This is the fastest I could think of:

```
public static int getSum(String str) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    int exp = 1;      
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        final char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            sum += (c - '0') * exp;
            exp *= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            exp = 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It iterates through string from right to left. Thanks to that, when it "sees" a digit it can add appropriate value, depending on the decimal position "seen" in the number.

### [Benchmark](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/c28961a5-ad2f-477c-be7c-be20e9167e4c#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName) using [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/)

Results are different than in [davecom's benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250888/performance-issue-in-string-to-number-conversion#answer-19250980):

```
AUTHOR       RUNTIME (NS)   HOW MANY TIMES FASTER THAN JUNS
-----------------------------------------------------------
Adam              66.221                                600
Old              579.873                                 70
Prabhakaran   20,012.750                                  2 (2x faster than Juns)
Juns          39,681.074                                  1
```

Comment: You need `s.charAt` not `str.charAt`. Would be faster if exp was multiplied by 10 instead of adding 1 - avoiding `Math.pow`.

Comment: Fastest answer here, see results in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can start improving the speed of the code by eliminating your isNum() method and using the built in Character.isDigit() method.

You may be able to further improve the speed by using a regular expression to extract the numbers out of each token instead of doing it with the loops.

Best of luck.

EDIT

Comparing the performance of some of the answers here, it would seem that @Prabhakaran's answer is slower than the original, while @OldCurmudgeon's is faster, and @Adam Stelmaszczyk's is the fastest :

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestSum {

    public static int doSum(String str){
        String[] sArray = str.split(" ");
        char[] chr = null;
        String temp;
        String number = "";
        int sum=0;
        for(String s : sArray){
            chr = s.toCharArray();
            for(char c : chr){
                temp = String.valueOf(c);
                if(isNum(temp)){
                    number = number + temp;
                }           
            }
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(number);
            number="";
        }       
        return sum;
    }

    public static boolean isNum(String nStr){   
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(nStr);
            return true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            return false;
        }       
    }

    public static void testSum1(){
        String str = "abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a";      
        str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" "));
        int sum=0;      
        for (String string : asList) {
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(string);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static int doSum2(String str) {
        int sum = 0;
        // -1 means not started.
        int start = -1;
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if ( Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                if ( start == -1 ) {
                    // Start of a number.
                    start = i;
                }
            } else {
                if ( start != -1 ) {
                    // End of a number.
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, i));
                    start = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( start != -1 ) {
            // A number at the end of the string.
            sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, str.length()));
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int getSum(String str) {
        int sum = 0;
        int exp = 1;      
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                sum += (c - '0') * exp;
                exp *= 10;
            }
            else{
                exp = 1;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        TestSum.testSum1();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("testSum1 took " + (endTime - startTime) + " nanoseconds");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(TestSum.doSum("abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a"));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("doSum took " + (endTime - startTime) + " nanoseconds");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(TestSum.doSum2("abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a"));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("doSum2 took " + (endTime - startTime) + " nanoseconds");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(TestSum.getSum("abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a"));
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("getSum took " + (endTime - startTime) + " nanoseconds");
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:desktop dave$ javac TestSum.java
Davids-MacBook-Air:desktop dave$ java TestSum
299
testSum1 took 1790000 nanoseconds
1379
doSum took 373000 nanoseconds
299
doSum2 took 173000 nanoseconds
299
getSum took 45000 nanoseconds
```

Comment: No need to do toCharArray -- charAt is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Benchmarking Java is not so easy... [Robust Java benchmarking, Part 1: Issues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html). I've updated my answer with benchmark using Caliper framework. It went out that Prabhakaran's code was faster than original.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String str = "abc123 ws32wd3 y3tg43 5tga89 a1a";      
    str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" "));
    int sum=0;      
    for (String string : asList) {
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
    System.out.println(asList);
    System.out.println(sum);
```

**Output**

str = [123, 32, 3, 3, 43, 5, 89, 1]

sum = 299

Comment: Unfortunately this is actually slower than his original code.  I tested it on my Mac running Java 7.  I posted the code and results in my answer.

Comment: According to benchmark in my post, it's 2x faster than the original code.

Answer (score 3):

For maximum performance you could try something like this:

```
public static int doSum(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  // -1 means not started.
  int start = -1;
  for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if ( Character.isDigit(ch)) {
      if ( start == -1 ) {
        // Start of a number.
        start = i;
      }
    } else {
      if ( start != -1 ) {
        // End of a number.
        sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, i));
        start = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  if ( start != -1 ) {
    // A number at the end of the string.
    sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, str.length()));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

prints `299` which my calculator confirms is 123+32+3+3+43+5+89+1

Comment: @davecom - I just noticed that! Fixing!

Comment: Indeed the fastest by my tests, see results in my comments.

Comment: @davecom - Thanks for the stats. Could you try [Adam's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19251545/823393) too? It has a charming simplicity and I think it has promise.

Comment: Indeed the fastest of all.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I tried mine too, check out my updated answer.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk - very elegant and truly fast. I expected mine to beat yours because I use `Integer.parseInt` which I expected to be native. We live and learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution would be parse that string with regex `\d` finding digits, and then go through the new string (which contains only digits) and sum up every sign (digit) in that string.

You won't even have to check if you are summing up digits, because regex will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to speed up your conversion you can use the following trick:
**int representation of number = character representation of number - '0'**

> So int 5 = char 5 - '0'
> or in other words
> int 5 = '5' - '0'

This is because of how the ASCII table is indexed.

Some (untested) code I wrote super fast to illustrate:

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
  if (!(str.charAt(i).isDigit()) continue;

  do {
    //now handle digit parsing into a number
    crtNumber= crtNumber*10 + str.charAt(i)-'0'
    i++
  } while(str.charAt(i).isDigit());

  queue.push(crtNumber);//save the number somewhere
  crtNumber= 0; //prepare for next round
}
```