# How can I convert a string(1,234) into a number(1234) using java

Tags: java

How can I convert a string

```
 (1,234)
```

into a number

```
(1234)
```

using java?

Comment: Is Google down? Folks, can anyone fling around a dead cat not to hit an answer to this question?

Comment: Replace the characer ',' with ''. See String API Docs.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao You can't know which **Locale** OP is in... There are locales where this is a valid integer, and some where this is considered a fraction...

Comment: thanks @SubirKumarSao, I'll do that.

Comment: `System.out.println("(1234)");` :)

Comment: @ppeterka66 I'm still struggling to find a duplicate on this site, however. Must be one somewhere...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Agreed `,` & `.` could mean opposite based on locale. But in this scenario it does not looks so.

Comment: that's what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java ?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Bingo! Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat  format = new DecimalFormat  ("#,###");
Number aNumber = format.parse("1,234");
System.out.println(aNumber.intValue());
```

Comment: If you'd add a notion of how locale can affect the decimal point, it would be a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `NumberFormat` for that

```
   String number = "1,234";
   NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
   int i = numberFormat.parse(number).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [String.repaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String value = "1,234";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(value.replaceAll(",", "")));
```

Comment: but i directly convert it as Integer. Why can i assign the replaced value again

Comment: I don't understand all the down-votes. This code example is correct. However you can remove `""+` in your `println` statement.

Comment: @DuncanJones I did not downvote and that comment was for the previous edit of this post.. Now it seems to be correct

Comment: @sanbhat jones didn't mean that cool

Comment: you edited your answer. check ur first one..

Comment: @Pawanmishra I know i edited the answer. At first i didn't convert as number. That's my fault

Comment: downvoting seems to be a fashion now.If downvoting why not leaving a comment

Comment: @javaBeginner you are correct

Comment: The best way to avoid down-votes is to fire up your IDE and test the code before you post.

Comment: @DuncanJones there is nothing wrong in my answer still downvote

Comment: @javaBeginner Did you post something incorrect and then correct it shortly after? If so, the down-voter may have not seen the correction. Otherwise, you are perhaps just the victim of the Internet and its mysterious ways.

Comment: @DuncanJones I think the second one is right

Comment: @javaBeginner Well... until 9 minutes ago you had a typo. Perhaps someone was being fussy. A comment wouldn't have hurt, of course.

Comment: @DuncanJones now also again downvote i mean after edit

Comment: @newuser congratulaions you got another downvote and me too

Comment: Here i thank to the beginning downvoters who indicate my mistake. But now the current downvotes doesn't know anything what i before did.

Comment: @newuser your answer is correct so +1 from myside

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = new String("1,234");
    String str1=str.replace(",", "");
    Integer.parseInt(str1);
```

try with the above code

**output**
1234

Comment: @downvoter if you are not getting output then please show the screenshot

Comment: All credits goes to the questionare

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable, so when you do replaceAll, you need to reassign object to string reference,

```
String str = new String("1,234");
str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
```

This works fine when tested.

Answer (score -2):

If speed was a **major** concern you may find something like this quite fast. It beat all comers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251545/823393) post.

```
int value(String s) {
  // Start at zero so first * 10 has no effect.
  int v = 0;
  // Work from the end of the string backwards.
  for ( int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    // Ignore non-digits.
    if ( Character.isDigit(c)) {
      // Mul curent by 10 and add digit value.
      v = (v * 10) + (c - '0');
    }
  }
  return v;
}
```

Comment: This seems a rather manual way of achieving the goal. Any reason this should be preferred to the more succinct answers?

Comment: @DuncanJones - It **may** be faster than all of the others if speed is a concern. Happy with a downvote or two ... it is only a route I would take if speed was critical. Added caveat.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't down-vote you myself - the answer looks correct. I was just interested in possible benefits. Some rather trigger happy down-voters circulating this question for some reason.

Comment: This is just reinventing of wheel and would require modifications if integer format in input string would change. OP wasn't concerned about speed.